# Finding the derivative for a product of two polynomial functions?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

In my problem, I am attempting to find $f'(x)$ when $f(x)=(5x^2-2x+8)(4x^2+7x-3)$. For my work I have:

\begin{align}
& \frac{d}{dx} (uv) = u\frac {dv}{dx} + v\frac {du}{dx} \\[8pt]
= {} & (5x^2-2x+8)(8x+7)+(4x^2+7x-3)(10x-2) \\[8pt]
= {} & 40x^3+35x^2-16x^2-14x+64x+56+40x^3-16x^2+70x^2-14x-30x+6 \\[8pt]
= {} & 80x^3 + 73x^2+6x+62
\end{align}

But when I plugged my original equation [$f(x)=(5x^2-2x+8)(4x^2+7x-3)$] into an [online derivative calculator](http://www.derivative-calculator.net/) to check my answer, it comes out as:

$$=80x^3+81x^2+6x+62\ldots\text{ ?}$$

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong (if I am)?

Comment: You have $-16x^2$ where it appears to me you need $-8x^2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: After checking the derivatives, the coefficient of $x^2$ must be $35-16-8+70=81$.

Comment: Why use the product rule?  ISTM you'd be better off just expanding everything and doing a term-by-term power rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \frac{d}{dx} (uv) = u\frac {dv}{dx} + v\frac {du}{dx} \\[8pt]
= {} & (5x^2-2x+8)(8x+7)+(4x^2+7x-3)(10x-2) \\[8pt]
= {} & 40x^3+35x^2-16x^2-14x+64x+56+40x^3-16x^2+70x^2-14x-30x+6 \\[8pt]
= {} & 80x^3 + 73x^2+6x+62
\end{align}

In the penultimate line of calculation, the 8th term from left should be $$4x^2 \times (-2) = -8x^2$$ instead of $(-16x^2)$. Correct that and then the answers will match.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I had intentionally put the wrong calculation to show the OP his mistake. Anyways he has realised it now.

Comment: thanks to you and Michael both!

Answer (score 3):

$4x^2 \cdot -2 = -8x^2$. You have written $-16x^2$. Purely an arithmetic mistake. Rest looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

When you multiply the second set of parenthesis, you write $4 \cdot -2 = -16$ instead of $-8$.

So you're $8$ off..

Answer (score 0):

HINT: after the product rule we get
$$f'(x)=(10x-2)(4x^2+7x-3)+(5x^2-2x+8)(8x+7)$$
after expanding we get
$$f'(x)=80 x^3+81 x^2+66 x+50$$

Comment: Isn't this what OP computed? Looks the same to me. There is a multiplication error in the next line though.

Comment: i will expand it